# France visa duration

Tags: visas, french-language

If I am traveling to France for 4 months and I apply for long stay visa, visa issued to me will be valid for 4months only or 6 months?

Comment: What kind of long stay visa do you mean?

Comment: I presume you are talking about a D visa. The start and end date will depend on what you want to do in France, e.g. the length of the academic year if you go for studies.